# In JSON parsing i am having issue at the time of dynamic parsing

Tags: iphone

I can't get exact out put after JSON parsing.

`strURLRootView` is `NSString` Object of "**RootViewController.m"** class...

```
strURLRootView = txt_EnterURL.text;
```

`strURLRank` is also the `NSString` Object of **"CheckRank_ViewController.m"** class...

```
strURLRank = strURLRootView;

-(void)viewDidLoad

{

    [self startJSONParsing];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)startJSONParsing

{

    responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    ArrData = [NSMutableArray array];

    NSString *stringWithoutSpaces = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://lsapi.seomoz.com/linkscape/url-metrics/%@%2fblog?AccessID=member-10fd5cb877&Expires=1365850483&Signature=m%2F7hZu1y7Sa00NGLFKHYY%2FO3TB4%3D",strURLRank];
```

if i use

@"http://lsapi.seomoz.com/linkscape/url-metrics/www.yahoo.com%2fblog?AccessID=member-10fd5cb877&Expires=1365850483&Signature=m%2F7hZu1y7Sa00NGLFKHYY%2FO3TB4%3D"

this URL Statically it will give exact out put.

```
    NSLog(@"stringWithoutSpaces is:--> %@\n\n",stringWithoutSpaces);

    NSURLRequest *request1 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:


                             [NSURL URLWithString:stringWithoutSpaces]];
    NSLog(@"request1 is:--> %@\n",request1);

    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request1 delegate:self];


}

(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response

{

    [responseData setLength:0];

}

(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data

{

    [responseData appendData:data];

}

(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error

{

    NSLog(@"Error occured at the time of parsing...");

}

(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection

{

    [connection release];
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [responseData release];

    results = [responseString JSONValue];

    lbl_RootDomain.text = [results objectForKey:@"upl"];
    lbl_URL.text = [results objectForKey:@"uu"];
    lbl_Title.text = [results objectForKey:@"ut"];
    lbl_SubDomain.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[[results objectForKey:@"fmrp"] floatValue]];
    lbl_MozRank.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[[results objectForKey:@"umrp"] floatValue]];
    lbl_DomainAutho.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[results objectForKey:@"pda"] intValue]];
    lbl_XternalLinks.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[results objectForKey:@"ueid"] intValue]];
    lbl_Links.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[results objectForKey:@"uid"] intValue]];
    lbl_PageAutho.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[[results objectForKey:@"upa"] floatValue]];

    NSLog(@"results data is:--> %@",results);

    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Root Domain: %@\n URL: %@\n Title: %@\n Subdomain mozRank: %@\n MozRank: %@\n Domain Authority: %@\n External Links: %@\n Links: %@\n Page Authority: %@\n",lbl_RootDomain.text,lbl_URL.text,lbl_Title.text,lbl_SubDomain.text,lbl_MozRank.text,lbl_DomainAutho.text,lbl_XternalLinks.text,lbl_Links.text,lbl_PageAutho.text];

    NSLog(@"mail data is:--> \n\n %@",str);
}
```

I am not getting the exact problem in coding. If i am wrong in coding then please tell me what is wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think its possible if strURLRank is return null value or also here if space then URL not support space ...check the value of strURLRank....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

......... Maulik Trambadiya Solution ..........

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [responseData setLength: 0];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{   
    [responseData appendData:data];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [connection release];
    [responseData release];

}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    responseData = nil;
    NSLog(@"%@",responseString);
    SBJsonParser *parser = [[[SBJsonParser alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSDictionary *responseDict = [parser objectWithString:responseString];
    NSLog(@"%@",responseDict);
    [responseDict retain];    
}

- (NSString*) _formEncodeString: (NSString*) string
{
    NSString* encoded = (NSString*) CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                            (CFStringRef) string, NULL, CFSTR("!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]"), kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
    return [encoded autorelease];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    ArrData = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSString *strURLRank=@"www.gmail.com";
    NSString *str=@"%2fblog?AccessID=member-10fd5cb877&Expires=1365850483&Signature=";
    NSString *str1=@"m%2F7hZu1y7Sa00NGLFKHYY%2FO3TB4%3D";
    NSString *stringWithoutSpaces = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://lsapi.seomoz.com/linkscape/url-metrics/%@",strURLRank];
    NSLog(@"%@",stringWithoutSpaces);

    stringWithoutSpaces=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",stringWithoutSpaces,str,str1];

  //  stringWithoutSpaces=[stringWithoutSpaces stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
   // stringWithoutSpaces = [stringWithoutSpaces stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",stringWithoutSpaces);

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:stringWithoutSpaces]];
    NSLog(@"%@",request);
   [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

......... Maulik Trambadiya Solution Finished..........

Answer (score 1):

after check that strURLRank is not null then use bellow code ...

```
NSString *stringWithoutSpaces = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://lsapi.seomoz.com/linkscape/url-metrics/%@%2fblog?AccessID=member-10fd5cb877&Expires=1365850483&Signature=m%2F7hZu1y7Sa00NGLFKHYY%2FO3TB4%3D",strURLRank];

NSString *urlString=[self trimString:stringWithoutSpaces];
```

and the use urlString.....

below method define in your .m file...

```
-(NSString*) trimString:(NSString *)theString {
    NSString *theStringTrimmed = [theString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    return theStringTrimmed;
}
```

hope this help you....
:)

Comment: then please give me which value you entered in textField means value of strURLRank...with NSLog and also  whole url NSLog...... i try to solve your problem...

Comment: i want to see your request1 is:--> 'yourURLHere' log which print here whole url,dude and insted of www.google.com,use www.facebook.com and after its not respond you then here problem in your URLRequest and problem is yourstring with special characters...

Comment: request1 is:--> <NSURLRequest http://lsapi.seomoz.com/linkscape/url-metrics/www.facebook.com24243509923615592832754182911158240671946484643413596429069549001920944900104258653817609092859770155235512501191759571332692071258971629622751876257411301320160727884504763439742509013722435012445491083912712309243101121263984619869122751841710742864800blog?AccessID=member-10fd5cb877&Expires=1365850483&Signature=m0.0000007hZu1y7Sa00NGLFKHYY0.000000O3TB425277676>

Comment: oh dude i think your AccessID and also memmberID are not used in this URL and also you are not authenticate for use this API so please follow this link and clear your proble dude...http://apiwiki.seomoz.org/w/page/29574176/SignedAuthentication :)its easy this is not your fault but first signup and get your accessID and MemberID....

Comment: i have already generated & used this AccessID as well as MemberID....then also it is giving the same output....

Comment: see this is your URL "http://lsapi.seomoz.com/linkscape/url-metrics/www.facebook.com24243509923615592832754182911158240671946484643413596429069549001920944900104258653817609092859770155235512501191759571332692071258971629622751876257411301320160727884504763439742509013722435012445491083912712309243101121263984619869122751841710742864800blog?AccessID=member-10fd5cb877&Expires=1365850483&Signature=m0.0000007hZu1y7Sa00NGLFKHYY0.000000O3TB425277676%3E" which main problem i get it from AddressBar here not perfect format for this API so error 401 is occured dude

Comment: and when you pass %2 its take a special code for some special characters see link so pass special code fo special character '%' like &#37;2fblog...

Comment: NSString *stringWithoutSpaces = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://lsapi.seomoz.com/linkscape/url-metrics/&#37;2fblog?AccessID=member-10fd5cb877&Expires=1365850483&Signature=m&#37;2F7hZu1y7Sa00NGLFKHYY&#37;2FO3TB4&#37;3D",strURLRank];
    
    
  NSLog(@"stringWithoutSpaces is:--> %@\n\n",stringWithoutSpaces);
    
    NSString *str = [stringWithoutSpaces stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&#37;" withString:@"%"];

NSURLRequest *request1 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
[NSURL URLWithString:str]];
    NSLog(@"request1 is:--> %@\n",request1);

Comment: Thank you very much @ Paras Joshi...

But the problem is having the garbage value attachment which is yet as it is & not solved.